# Collapsed methods expands after IDE restart

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I fold (collapse) some method in Android project in IntelliJ IDEA either via plus sign or via "right click->Folding->Collapse". I close IntelliJ. After I reopen the IDE, the methods are unfolded (expanded) again.

Is there a way to solve this? It this IDE's bug or I can fix this in IDE's properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folding of individual methods is not saved. The folding settings can be found here: File --> Settings --> Editor --> Code Folding

Comment: Thanks. I do not see any option so save foldings. Do you?

Comment: That's what I am saying, if you fold a method and close IDEA, the fold is not saved. But if you want to, say, have all Inner Classes folded by default, then you can save that setting here.

Comment: I understood that. But as with anyone else, I generally do not want folding of those elements. But, when I work in a long file I like to fold all the part I do not need to work on and this is when I need fold to remember my current foldings. But, it seems I will have to live without it. Do you happen to know if custom area foldings (Ctrl+.) are saved on restart?

Comment: Not sure about what "anyone else" does, but the default folding scheme is persisted.